# How to find the words with which ".*" was satisfied in regex test

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string and regular expression:

```
var str = 'abcSSSdefghEEEijSSSkEEElmnSSSEEEop',
    regex = /abc.*ij.*lmn.*op/g;
```

`regex.test(str)` returns `true` ([see here](http://regex101.com/r/lG9uT5)).

I want to get an array with each of the substrings matched by each `.*` in the regular expression.

For example, with the string above, I want a function which returns the following array:

```
['SSSdefghEEE', 'SSSkEEE', 'SSSEEE']
```

I have read through MDN's docs for [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), but there is no callback to store the matched values in.

How can I accomplish the above?

Comment: Use `var matched = str.match(/abc(.*)ij(.*)lmn(.*)op/);`

Comment: That would be `str.match(regex)`, but I  don't see how that regex would give the expected result, it would match the entire string

Comment: What you're looking for is called a "match group" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is the function you're looking for, which returns the matches instead of `true`/`false`.

Here's a function that does what you're looking for ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfrohs/9aQ7j/)):

```javascript
function matchAlphabet(str) {
    // Parentheses specify what should be returned by `match()` as a match
    var reg = /abc(.*)ij(.*)lmn(.*)op/,
        matches = str.match(reg);

    // Remove first item (in this case, the full string)
    matches.shift();

    return matches;
}

var matches = matchAlphabet("abcSSSdefghEEEijSSSkEEElmnSSSEEEop");
// ["SSSdefghEEE","SSSkEEE","SSSEEE"]
```

Comment: also this http://jsfiddle.net/9aQ7j/3/ one not worked.. How can i get this one worked??

Comment: @user3585284 When you use the `g` flag, `match()` returns *each* match matched by the regex as a new array item (and doesn't include the original string, so `shift()` isn't needed. Groups (parentheses) do *not* add additional items ([this](http://jsfiddle.net/bfrohs/9aQ7j/7/) and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bfrohs/9aQ7j/8/) have the same results). From your fiddle, though, I'm guessing you're looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bfrohs/9aQ7j/10/). It uses `execute()` instead, which allows for looping through each set of matches.

Comment: @user3585284 If that last fiddle isn't what you're looking for, give me a couple strings for input, and the array output you're looking to get back, and I'll see what I can do for you :)

Answer (score 1):

test is the wrong method for this. you want to use "exec"

[See link -> "Methods"](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)